# why laravel save() works like this (returns false sometime)

Tags: php, laravel

how does laravel `$user->save()` works?

I am interested in the following.

1) I know this save() method might return exception or false. I always want it to return exception and I never want it to return false at all.  how do I achieve that?

2) when does save() return false? i think it should return exceptions all the time if it doesn't work.

Comment: Check out the comments in [Model.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php). `If the "saving" event returns false we'll bail out of the save and return false, indicating that the save failed. This provides a chance for any listeners to cancel save operations if validations fail or whatever.` If you want to throw an exception, check for false, then throw your own exception.

Answer (score 2):

For #1, you can extend the Model and throw an exception when false:

```
class BaseModel extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function save(array $options = [])
    {
        $saved = parent::save($options);
        if ($saved === false) {
            throw new \Exception("some text");
        }
    }
}
```

or  just check for false:

```
$saved = $model->save();
if ($saved === false) {
    throw new \Exception("some text");
}
```

For #2, you can check the source code here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L641

and check the possibilities of `return false`.

Comment: why does it ever return false? this is the question

Comment: At some point you need to `read`. It's explictly says "If the "saving" event returns false we'll bail out of the save and return false".

Comment: Might be more clear to grab line 648, the saving event returns false, and thats why save returns false.